# Find $P\left(X ≤ \frac12, Y≥\frac34\right)$. Joint Probability Density Function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Textbook: Mathematical Statistics with Applications Wackerly

Let $X$ and $Y$ have the joint probability density function given by 
$$f(x,y) = \cases{6(1-y), \quad 0≤x≤y≤1 \\ 
0, \quad \text{elsewhere}}$$

Find $P\left(X ≤ \frac34, Y≥\frac12\right)$

The correct integral is supposed to be
$$\int_{1/2}^1\int_{1/2}^16(1-y)\text{ dy dx }+\int_{1/2}^{3/4}\int_{x}^{1}6(1-y)\text{ dy dx }$$

This makes no sense to me. Aren't we only interested in the small triangular region under the density function $f(x,y) = 6(1-y)$? This integral 
$$\int_{1/2}^{3/4}\int_{1/2}^{x}6(1-y)\text{ dy dx }$$ makes more sense to me.

Comment: This is simply a typo in the first integral, the whole formula for $P(X\leqslant3/4,Y\geqslant1/2)$ should read $$\int_{\color{red}{0}}^{\color{red}{1/2}}\int_{1/2}^16(1-y)\mathrm dy\mathrm dx+\int_{1/2}^{3/4}\int_{x}^{1}6(1-y)\mathrm dy\mathrm dx.$$

Comment: @Did By this you mean there is an error by the authors?

Comment: Indeed. We wish to integrate over the interval where $0\leq x\leq 3/4$ and $\max\{x,1/2\}\leq y\leq 1$. Obviously that maximum is $1/2$ when $0\leq x\leq 1/2$ and the maximum is $x$ when $1/2<x\leq 3/4$.

Comment: A typo, yes. (You might wish to keep "error" for more serious matters...)

Comment: I don't understand the need for the two integrals in this case.

Comment: Simple: the lower limit of the inner integral for each $x$ in $(0,3/4)$ should be $\max(x,1/2)$, hence the decomposition into $0<x<1/2$ (and then $\max(x,1/2)=1/2$) and $1/2<x<3/4$ (and then $\max(x,1/2)=x$).

Comment: @Did This is strange because in an example that is very similar to this one the authors handled it with a single double integral. $$P\left(0≤X≤\frac12, \frac14≤Y\right) = \int_\frac14^\frac12 \int_\frac14^x 3x dydx$$

Comment: In this other example, the support of the distribution might be restricted to $y<x$. Anyway, what do you find strange?

Comment: You are correct about the support of that distribution. The first integral in your very first comment is what is strange to me. It seems like there are two regions we are interest in, rather than one.